# How to swim before work (wet towel and clothes problem)?

Tags: efficiency, time, sports

I like to swim on an almost daily basis, just before going to work. So first I go by bicycle to the swimming pool, swim, and then go by bike to the office. For what it's worth, choosing the best way:

```
(Home) --------[4km]-----> (Swimming pool) ---[2km]---> (Office)
```

I don't have time to go back home and put the wet swimming bag and towel and so on where they belong. And in in the office I stay considerably long. And I wouldn't like to have them wet the whole day since the towel would smell bad.

Is there a solution for this small problem? What do people do to swim before work?

Comment: wait, so you bike to the pool, then swim to the office? ;-)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

- Get a locker at the gym that you can leave things in during the day. Leave your towel & swim suit hanging there during the day and pick them up (mostly or completely dry) on the way home.
- Use a swimmer's towel. They work very well when wet, yet wring out and dry quickly. Still leaves the suit wet, though.
- Get a large Zip-lock™ (or other brand of sliding zipper bag), seal the wet stuff in it during the day, and throw it in the wash/dryer when you get home. It will likely get stinky during the day, but it won't bother your office mates & you can deal with it in the privacy of your house later.

Comment: In my experience zip lock bags often break, tear or pop open - I'd suggest a dry bag from an outdoors shop ([random example](http://www.ellis-brigham.com/products/sea-to-summit-ultra-sil-dry-sack-8l/253143)) - they're designed to be robust, light, dependable and stay sealed 100%. They're also handy things to have for lots of other uses like keeping stuff dry when camping, packing dirty clothes while travelling, etc

Comment: I guess that would fit somewhere within the definition of "or other brand of sliding zipper bag". :) It got the creative juices flowing, and that was the important thing.

Comment: Oh yes, it's definitely not a criticism, I'm just mentioning that these sort of bags exist, and are really handy and reliable.

Answer (score 5):

Some pools provide towels to their swimmers, and also provide spinning things that quickly dry bathing suits. It might be worth looking for such a place.

If this pool is your only option, can you hang up your bathing suit and damp towel at the office, perhaps on a coat hook or the like? I would probably hang up the suit first, then put the towel over it so other people don't see the suit. Even if you then put a coat over all of that, they will dry and air a little so they will not get musty and smelly.

Comment: +1 for the spin-dryer. I used it regularly. At first I was afraid it'll destroy my swimsuit or make it wear out quickly, but it was really ok. If there's none in the swimming pool, you can try to convince the pool's HQs to purchase one.

Comment: You could get your own [salad spinner](https://www.google.com/search?q=salad+spinner&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) if the facility doesn't have one.

Answer (score 5):

Dry yourself and your swimwear using a hairdryer or hand-dryer at the pool. Then you won't need a towel.

Comment: This might also work if you wring it out first, IDK if this would get it completely dry. But it would do most of the work probs :)

Comment: However, your swimsuit will wear out pretty quickly if you dry it by a hairdryer.

Answer (score 4):

Drop the wet clothes at a laundry on your way to office. Pick them up while returning. Not cost-effective though, I can't think of a better solution for the wet towel.

Answer (score 1):

***You could:***

- Try wearing less clothes and wear clothes that dry faster. This way there are less clothes to dry and the clothes dry faster.
- You could try wringing the clothes out and spreading them across your bike, as you ride or even after. This way they can dry as you go to work(or not), and there might be a place with good ventilation where you can hang them to dry further.
- You may use both of these methods, they should work better together.

---

*Note: At the office if the clothes are still not dry you can try to iron them dry or set in front of a fan draped over a chair, coat rack, etc.*

Comment: I don't think we speak about "clothes", we speak about a "speedo" here, AFAIK.

Comment: I can't telling a story in my mind of a user who suggests "wear fewer clothes" as a life-hack in answer to every question... :p

Comment: I can just envision the Speedo™ flapping from the handle bars, while the towel is wrapped around the shoulders and held on with a clothes pin, superhero style! _It's a bird! It's a plane! No, it's Super-Swimmer-Biker!!!_ :)

Answer (score 1):

Ask the swimming pool personnel for a solution. They may have practical solutions already working for other guests.

Comment: this may be a comment, not an answer. See if you can expand on thi a bit to offer a helpful solution...

Answer (score 0):

Bring extra dress from your home. Get a locker from Swimming pool. After swimming change your dress and keep your wet dress to the locker. Don't forget to bring back to your home when you return from your office

Answer (score 0):

Leave the bag of wet clothes/towel with your bike?

Answer (score 0):

- Wear the minimal swimmers, not something bulky like board shorts.
- Get a microfibre towel.
- You could even string it around your bike frame to dry when you are riding.